# need help understanding Andrew NG ML Backpropogation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I was referring to a code to implement Andrew NG's course in Python. I don't understand what exactly is the happening in the last 2 lines of the for loop (grad1 and grad2).

```
grad1 = np.zeros((Theta1.shape))
grad2 = np.zeros((Theta2.shape))

for i in range(m):
    xi= X[i,:] # 1 X 401
    a1i = a1[i,:] # 1 X 26
    a2i =a2[i,:] # 1 X 10
    d2 = a2i - y10[i,:]
    d1 = Theta2.T @ d2.T * sigmoidGradient(np.hstack((1,xi @ Theta1.T)))
    grad1= grad1 + d1[1:][:,np.newaxis] @ xi[:,np.newaxis].T
    grad2 = grad2 + d2.T[:,np.newaxis] @ a1i[:,np.newaxis].T
    
grad1 = 1/m * grad1
grad2 = 1/m * grad2

grad1_reg = grad1 + (Lambda/m) * np.hstack((np.zeros((Theta1.shape[0],1)),Theta1[:,1:]))
grad2_reg = grad2 + (Lambda/m) * np.hstack((np.zeros((Theta2.shape[0],1)),Theta2[:,1:]))
```

Comment: It looks like an order 2 regularization term with coefficient `Lambda` assuming the first column of each `Theta` is the bias (not regularized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1[1:][:,np.newaxis] @ xi[:,np.newaxis].T
```

calculates the partial gradient w.r.t. Theta1, and

```
d2.T[:,np.newaxis] @ a1i[:,np.newaxis].T
```

for Theta2. They can be derived by chain rule.
The for loop sums up the gradient from each batch of data.

Comment: why is 'np.newaxis' used?

Comment: First, both Theta1 and Theta2 are matrices, and scalar-by-matrix gradient should be a matrix. Second, the dimension comment in the code fragment is a little bit confusing and may lead to misunderstanding. The 1-dim numpy array is actually a vector with dimension (401,), (26,), (10,), instead of an explicit row-vector indicated by the comment. Therefore, the four np.newaxis used here transfers the corresponding variables into explicit column-vectors. Then the matrix multiplication of a column-vector and a row-vector gives a matrix, the dimension of which is the same as Theta1 or Theta.

Comment: I wrote a deduction of the BP in a two-layer neural network with explicit bias terms. You can refer to this if interested, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4UestG-JI-XcC0mC5tYp34p_Bt9MX3n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a reference for 1-dim numpy array, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284995/are-1-dimensional-numpy-arrays-equivalent-to-vectors

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response really helped me understanding BP better.